# passing command line arguments between classes in Java

Tags: java

I have a Java program in which I need to accept the command line arguments in an array as input in the `main` method, and then need to pass the array to a constructor of another class in the same program. I need to know how to declare the array globally and then how to pass it and take it in the constructor.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need to declare the array globally (in java its `public`) to pass it in any constructor? Since you will be invoking the `constructor` from the main method itself, you can pass the array that you get as commandline argument, to the constructor.

Comment: Don't consider using global variables. As to passing information into a constructor, you give the accepting class's constructor a parameter that will accept the data, and you pass it in when calling this constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Example{

  Example(String s[])
  { 
   AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass(s);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
  int num=args.length;
  String s[]=new String[num]; 
  Example ex = new Example (s);`
  }
}
```

And you can create `AnotherClass`

```
public class AnotherClass{
  AnotherClass(String s[])
  { 
   // array argument constructor
  }
}
```

You can run using

`javac Example.java`

`java Example`

Comment: I cannot call the AnotherClass from the Main() method but I need to call it from the constructor of Example class and I have 2 arrays. So Do you first want me to pass the 2 arrays from the main() method to the constructor of the Example class and then from the constructor call the AnotherClass with the arrays? If possible, can you please show me the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeOtherClass{
   public SomeOtherClass(String[] args){
       this.arguments = args;
   }
   private String[] arguments;
}
class YourMainClass{

 public static void main(String[] args){
     SomeOtherClass cl = new SomeOtherClass(args);
    //fanny's your aunt
  }
}
```

This is how you can pass the arguments to SomeOtherClass's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In your class that contains the main method, you could have a class variable like:

```
String[] cmdLineArgs;
```

then in the main method:

```
cmdLineArgs = new String[args.length];
this.cmdLineArgs = args;
```

and then just implement a getter that will return `cmdLineArgs`. Then to call another constructor:

```
YourObject x = new YourObject(yourFirstClass.getCmdLineArgs());
```

(you don't need all those steps if you're calling this other constructor from the main method of course, you can just call the constructor with `args` directly)